# Where is the hardware write-protect screw on the Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm trying to find the hardware write-protect for the Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571. I believe its the same hardware as the C910, and should have the same screw but I can't find documentation for either of those anywhere. The ID is "Yuna".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture of the write-protect screw:

[image: https://wiki.galliumos.org/images/9/97/WP-screw-02.jpg]